# Handling Turkish/Non-ascii Characters in subprocess.check_output in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, subprocess, ssid

I am encountering an issue with handling Turkish characters when using the `subprocess.check_output` method in Python. My objective is to retrieve Wi-Fi profile names on a Windows system, which may contain Turkish characters such as 'İ', 'ü', 'ş'. However, when using `subprocess.check_output` with encoding set to either 'utf-8', 'ISO-8859-9', or 'windows-1254', the Turkish characters are not correctly represented.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import subprocess

try:
    command_output = subprocess.check_output("netsh wlan show profile", shell=True, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
    # Also tried with 'ISO-8859-9' and 'windows-1254'
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Command error: {e}")
    command_output = ""
```

The issue arises with Wi-Fi names containing Turkish characters, for instance, 'İnternetim' ("my internet") or 'AĞIM' ("my network"). These characters are either omitted or replaced with incorrect characters, like '˜nternet

I ran my code and I got this error on wifi with Turkish profile names.

> Profile error nternetim: Command 'netsh wlan show profile "nternetim" key=clear' returned non-zero exit status 1.
> Profil işlenirken hata AIM: Command 'netsh wlan show profile "AIM" key=clear' returned non-zero exit status 1.

As seen in the code output, letters are missing.

Also tried with 'ISO-8859-9' and 'windows-1254'.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'İnternet'.encode( 'cp857').decode( 'cp1254')` returns `'˜nternet'`… Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no guarantee as to which character encoding any SSID uses, you just have to guess. Take out the `encoding` keyword and you will receive bytes, which you can then successively try to decode according to whatever heuristics you can come up with.

```
import subprocess

try:
    command_output = subprocess.check_output("netsh wlan show profile", shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Command error: {e}")
    command_output = ""

for encoding in ('utf-8', 'ISO-8859-9', 'windows-1254'):
    try:
        command_output = command_output.decode(encoding)
        break
    except UnicodeDecodingError:
        pass
    else:
        raise UnicodeDecodingError("Could not find a valid encoding for '%r'" % command_output)
```

UTF-8 is nicely robust in that it will reject most strings which are not valid UTF-8. The other legacy 8-bit encodings will often gladly accept pretty much any string without errors, but result in bogus data if you guess incorrectly.

You might want to add more encodings, and/or see if you can perform some sort of frequency analysis on the strings to establish the most likely encoding. (The `chardet` library provides some facilities for this.)

Comment: I don't think you need the `shell=True` either on Windows, but Windows is weird, and I fortunately don't have any way to test this.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/ for some hints if you need to manually establish an encoding.